# How to submit Xamarin iOS app with Native Reference to AppStore?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, spatialite

I'm working on a **Xamarin Forms app which includes this SpatialiteForms library**.
https://github.com/breekmd/SpatialiteForms

*When I try to submit the iOS app to the AppStore it is rejected during the validation.*

Just wondering if anybody else have/had this issue and if yes, how it was resolve?

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 and XCode.

When I checked the architecture of the iOSSpatialite framework, it is saying `iOSSpatialite is architecture: x86_64` (see below)

```
lipo -info iOSSpatialite
Non-fat file: iOSSpatialite is architecture: x86_64
```

Would it be possible to have it as arm64?

**See message below related to the rejection:**

```
*Publishing project 'PROJECT_NAME' completed with errors.
App Store bundle validation failed for archive PROJECT_NAME
"altool" exited with code 67.
Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support.
Unsupported Architectures. The executable for PROJECT_NAME.iOS.app/Frameworks/iOSSpatialite.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64]'.
Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'PROJECT_NAME.iOS.app/Frameworks/iOSSpatialite.framework/Frameworks/mod_spatialite_arm64.7.dylib' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure.
Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at 'PROJECT_NAME.iOS.app/Frameworks/iOSSpatialite.framework/iOSSpatialite' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version.
The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker.
Invalid architecture: Apps that include an app extension and framework must support arm64.
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'PROJECT_NAME.iOS.app/Frameworks/iOSSpatialite.framework' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.*
```

Thanks,
S.